# PHP - How to include php script without it running before including

Tags: php, file, include

In my file *index.php* I have included this text from another file.

```
<title>
  <?php

  $title = "";
  if (basename(__FILE__, ".php") == "index") {
    $title = "Home";
  } else {
    $title = ucfirst(basename(__FILE__, ".php"));
  }

  echo $title;
  ?>
</title>
```

And I guess you can see what i does, and if not, then it's supposed to set the title to the basename of the file. So say you have a file called *downloads.php*, then the title with this script would be *Downloads*. But I have this problem which I don't know how to get past. When I include the text via.

```
<head>
  include "filename.php";
</head>
```

And my problems is when I include the text, the 'script' runs before it includes. Say if the name of the file you included is *filename.php* and the main page where you have included the text is *main.php*, the header would be *Filename* and not *Main*. And the reason why I want to include the text, and not just paste directly into *main.php* is because it's much easier to edit if you have multiple files where you need the exact same code.

I hope you understand what I'm asking, and that you are able to help me.

Comment: That's pretty much the whole point of PHP includes.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`:

```
if (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], ".php") == "index") {
    $title = "Home";
  } else {
    $title = ucfirst(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], ".php"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to set up a simple system for breaking your pages up into "subpages". Good idea. But rather than relying on the filename, why don't you set a variable? For example:

In `page_title.php`:

```
<?php
echo "<title>" . $title . "</title>";
```

In `index.php`:

```
<?php $title = "Home"; ?>
<head>
    <?php include "page_title.php"; ?>
</head>
```

In `some_other_page.php`:

```
<?php $title = "Some Other Page"; ?>
<head>
    <?php include "page_title.php"; ?>
</head>
```

And the same for any other pages you want...

In fact, you probably want to encapsulate the whole `<head></head>` section of your page.

Finally, rather than reinventing the wheel, you might want to look at some of the templating engines out there for PHP. I like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net), but there are others. These templating engines make it possible to write template files (including other template if necessary) and make it easy to simply pass variables to the template & render your HTML.

Comment: The point was though to make it automatic so I wouldn't have to do it myself everytime i create a new page. But thanks anyways, and I'm going to look into those engines. Sounds like a good idea.